# textbox text_changed event handling

Tags: asp.net, events, textbox, textchanged

I have 8 text boxes in a form. And each text box changed event the text in the text box should be saved to Database. Is there any better approach than firing each text box's text changed event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use only one event handler for all the text boxes and use the sender argument to get the changed text.
2. You could put all of the textboxes in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so that the page is not refreshed even if you set AutoPostBack to true.
3. You would write a PageMethod that receives the element to update and the updated text. This method could be called using AJAX and jQuery. [This](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) blog by Dave Ward should get you started.

Comment: Can you explain the pagemethod please..Thanks in advance

Comment: Added a link to a blog that does a good job explaining them. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is using the timer. Have a timer that ticks every 1000 ms (say) and checks the textBox.Text.